# Kubernetes UI on Google Container Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there any way to access the UI on the GKE service?

I tried following the information on https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.0.6/docs/user-guide/ui.md 
And got this

```
Error: 'empty tunnel list.'
Trying to reach: 'http://10.64.xx.xx:8080/'
```

Is this feature turned on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that the master can't communicate with the nodes in your cluster. Have you deleted the instances from your cluster, or messed with the firewalls? There should be a firewall allowing access SSH to the nodes in the cluster from the master's IP address, and an entry in your project-wide metadata with the master's public SSH key.

Comment: I can SSH to the individual nodes from the outside. I have deleted a few instances in the past but the cluster is healthy atm.  I'm not too sure how to debug the master to node firewall issues, but I assume if that was the case, many of the kubectl commands would be failing

Comment: Follow up: Readding the "allow ssh from everywhere" solved this for me, outlined in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/wiki/Debugging-FAQ/3dcb9f585d9801e1702922b01d6415bfef8a8df7#gce

Answer (score 1):

Something to check.. make sure you haven't added ssh keys to the cluster nodes metadata.  I did this a few weeks back... opened a support case.. and found that  I should have added the keys to the project metadata instead.

Comment: This was the issue in my case. I moved my SSH key from the instance level to the project level and everything started working.